CMake Target Definitions Management in QtCreator
Configuration :
QtCreator (12.0.2)
CMake (3.27.7)
I encounter the following problem, my CMakeLists.txt file contains several targets definition to be able to compile two versions of software on a single build request :
add_executable(MY_SOFTWARE
    WIN32
    ${MY_SOFTWARE_CORE_SOURCES}
    ${MY_SOFTWARE_CORE_HEADERS}
)
add_executable(MY_SOFTWARE_EXTENDED
    WIN32
    ${MY_SOFTWARE_CORE_SOURCES}
    ${MY_SOFTWARE_CORE_HEADERS}
    ${MY_SOFTWARE_CORE_SOURCES_EXTENDED}
    ${MY_SOFTWARE_CORE_HEADERS_EXTENDED}
)
target_compile_definitions(MY_SOFTWARE_EXTENDED PRIVATE
    -DEXTENDED_VERSION
)

My problem is that QtCreator does not care about the definition. My code appears in grayed out.
However, i have two possibities to open the source file from the Source Tree & i tried to select the source under MY_SOFTWARE_EXTENDED or under MY_SOFTWARE, it does not affect anything.
I found that i can use the add_definition command from cmake but unfortunately i would like to have different definitions. How could improve the management of this kind of configurations ?

Removed the CMake tag because your CMake code is fine. This is purely a QT creator issue. I suggest you consult Qt support.

When multiple parse context are available for the same file, you can usually select the one you want on the top bar that displays the filename and the outline, next to the #. If changing it doesn't fix the issue, you should report a bug and contact the Qt support as the previous comment suggested.
You might also try to restart clangd (option available in the same bar) if just changing the context is not enough.
